# How to increment a date using Arrow?

Tags: python, datetime, arrow-python

I'm using the [arrow](http://crsmithdev.com/arrow/) module to handle `datetime` objects in Python. If I get current time like this:

```
now = arrow.now()
```

...how do I increment it by one day?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

**Update as of 2020-07-28**

**Increment the day**

```
now.shift(days=1)
```

**Decrement the day**

```
now.shift(days=-1)
```

---

**Original Answer**

*DEPRECATED as of 2019-08-09*

https://arrow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/releases.html

- 0.14.5 (2019-08-09) [CHANGE] Removed deprecated replace shift functionality. Users looking to pass plural properties to the replace function to shift values should use shift instead.
- 0.9.0 (2016-11-27) [FIX] Separate replace & shift functions

**Increment the day**

```
now.replace(days=1)
```

**Decrement the day**

```
now.replace(days=-1)
```

[I highly recommend the docs.](https://arrow.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#replace-shift)

Comment: According to the *highly recommended docs* `replace` will just alter the attribute and `shift` will move it relatively. There is no `days` attribute for `replace`, but there is `day` which changes the date to given value.
Why is this the accepted answer when `shift` is the correct solution?

Comment: @nik surely you know the answer to your own question.  Things change.  But just in case you're familiar with the docs but not the changelog, you can find when the api changed here: https://arrow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/releases.html.

Comment: Thanks for updating--was helpful for a quick reminder this evening :-)

Answer (score 5):

The [docs](https://arrow.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) state that `shift` is to be used for adding offsets:

`now.shift(days=1)`

The `replace` method with arguments like `days`, `hours`, `minutes`, etc. seems to work just as shift does, though replace also has `day`, `hour`, `minute`, etc. arguments that **replace** the value in given field with the provided value.

In any case, I think e.g. `now.shift(hours=-1)` is much clearer than `now.replace`.

Comment: *Curiously*, `days`, `hours`, `minutes` are no longer known to `replace`. The way to go **now** is `now.shift(days=1)` as you have correctly answered.

Answer (score -1):

See [documentation](https://arrow.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#replace-shift)

```
now = arrow.now()
oneDayFromNow = now.replace(days+=1)
```